# Django form with more fields as needed

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to specify a django form so that a user can add more fields to it.

E.g. A user needs to list 4 names but only three fields are initially present on the page. The user would then be able to press a button and add another field for the fourth name.

I am currently doing this using javascript and httprequest.

Comment: you need something like this: http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/- define formsets, and use jquery to show/hide them as needed.

Comment: That looks pretty much like what I want. Thanks.

Comment: ill just make this an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need something like this: [django dynamic formsets](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/)

define formsets, and use jquery to show/hide them as needed

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with easy javascript as suggested.

**But remember that your new fields (all fields that are not predefined in the form class) will not be used in Djangos validations.**

So if you plan to put this data into your database you have to deal with the cleaning and escaping of the content you self.